# How to pas state of component up to parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-context, recompose

I'm using FormContainer component which receive initialValue(basically empty strings that represents inputs values) and handleSubmit function from parent. 
 FormContainer have state witch contains inputs values, onChange method for updating state, onSubmit method. I'm using react context to pass onChange  to inputs and onSubmit to submit button.

FormContainer code:

```
export const FormContext = React.createContext(null);

class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = props.initialValue;
}

onChange(name, value) {
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
}

onSubmit(){
  const stateKostul = this.state;
  console.log(stateKostul);
  this.props.handleSubmit(stateKostul);
}

render() {
  const value={
    formState: this.state,
    onChange: (name, value) => this.onChange(name, value),
    onSubmit: () =>this.onSubmit(),
  };
  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={value}>
      {this.props.children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  ); 
 }
}
```

I use it in AddProductForm component/scene. Also i use recompose to add handler for fetching data.

AddProductForm code:

```
function AddProductForm({ handleSubmit }) {
  const initialValue = {
    title: '',
    location: '',
    description: '',
    photos: [],
    price: '',
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.container}>
      <h2 className={s.formTitle}>Add product</h2>
      <div className={s.formContainer}>
        <FormContainer 
         initialValue={initialValue}
         handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
           // custom inputs and submit button
        </FormContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const enhancer = compose(
  withHandlers({
    handleSubmit: ({stateKostul}) => () => {
      console.log('it works!');
      console.log(stateKostul);
      //fetch to server
    },
  }),
);

export default enhancer(AddProductForm);
```

So my problem is that i dont know how to pass data from state of FormContainer to AddProductForm. When i pass state of FormContainer to my handler from props i get undefind. But from onSubmit state is ok.

And i can't fetch data from FormContainer because of idea behind FormContainer: it supposed to be universal to any form.

Any ideas how can i get data from FormContainer without changing it's structure?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with FormContext/Enhancer, however I think your error is in your enhancer.
You are destructuring the object returned from the onSubmit handler looking for the property "stateKostul". "stateKostul" probably isn't defined in FormContainer's state. That's just the name of the variable you passed into it.

Try to change:

```
handleSubmit: ({stateKostul}) => () => {
      console.log('it works!');
      console.log(stateKostul);
      //fetch to server
}
```

to:

```
handleSubmit: (stateKostul) => () => {
      console.log('it works!');
      console.log(stateKostul);
      //fetch to server
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed AddProductForm from functional component to class component and added method handleSubmit. Guess the problem was about context. Not sure how but it works now

here is my code:

```
class AddProductForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      location: '',
      description: '',
      photos: [],
      price: '',
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(stateKostul) {
    console.log('it works!');
    console.log(stateKostul);
    //fetch to server
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.container}>
        <h2 className={s.formTitle}>Add product</h2>
        <div className={s.formContainer}>
          <FormContainer initialValue={this.state} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            // custom inputs and submit button
          </FormContainer>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```